# Ubuntu 18.04 not booting up: iwlwifi .. :BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios, iwlwifi

when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> terminal appears and works fine but while Ubuntu login screen is booting up this issue appears

```
iwlwifi .. :BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

And my Ubuntu 18.04 is not booting up in the start. 
I haven't found solution to this problem. Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Answering the question in a comment as I do not have enough reputation to post an answer! 

I was facing the same issue on my Ubuntu 18.04 and the reason for the same was gdm3 service in stopped state. The screen following the error screen allowed me to login using my username and password on a CLI (instead of GUI) and then running the following command started the GUI as usual - `sudo service gdm3 start`

Answer (score 3):

See [Ubuntu not booting due to iwlwifi error-BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255680/ubuntu-not-booting-due-to-iwlwifi-error-bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds)

In a nutshell:

1. Boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)
2. Choose *Enable network*, and wait for the process to complete.
3. Choose *Drop to root shell prompt*.
4. Reinstall the desktop manager packages with `apt install ubuntu-desktop`
5. Then reboot.

The boot process should progress as usual, and you should be able to log in.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by going to *Recovery mode* → *Enable network*. In *Repair broken packages* input:

```
$ apt update  
$ apt dist-upgrade
```