# Ubuntu not booting due to iwlwifi error-BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, startup

I updated Ubuntu 20.04 to 5.4-40 kernal update, since then I am unable to boot up into ubuntu.
I am having Windows 10 and ubuntu dual-booted.
[image: error]
This is while bootup.

Comment: Did you try with a previous kernel?

Comment: yes with 5.4-39 ..all was working fine.

Comment: Then you should stick to that. It is probably a bug that will be fixed within the next few kernel updates.

Comment: hmm ok...But any possibility of reverting the changes?..so that i can use older one until the bug is fixed

Comment: You can do that. You can select the previous one in the Grub menu. I thought you already meant that with the 5.4-39.

Comment: Yes i found 5.4-39 in grub..But I am able to boot only in recovery mode...not as Normal boot (both 39 and 40)

Comment: In that case this is not a simple matter of kernel bug. Something else happened. Would be good to know what else was updated beside the kernel. Also, as far as I see on the internet, this error can only cause wireless problems, not boot problems. So your problem might be totally unrelated to it. This is also a possibility.

Comment: So any suggestions what can i do now?

Comment: Please describe EXACTLY what you do when trying to boot -39. Does -39 boot fully? Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema ,Yes with 39 also I m facing same issue...Its stuck at boot-time with that error....Only in recovery mode I m able to boot....and Yes I have Live USB

Comment: And I select 39-boot from advance boot options from Grub menu . In both the boots its stuck at the same screen...Please Help!

Comment: Let's try some quick things to eliminate easy stuff. In the BIOS, make sure SECURE BOOT is disabled. At the GRUB prompt, hit "e" to enter edit mode, find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset" and then CTRL-X or F10 to continue boot. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: If you get it to boot, via Recovery Mode, or a full boot, show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model of your computer or motherboard. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, Here is the o/p `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` is F.06 and model of computer is HP Pavilion Laptop 14-ce1xxx. And even after changing quiet splash to quiet splash nomodeset,i was unable to boot. Same error I m getting.

Comment: Did you solve it

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem. Turns out the reason was that I had removed a couple of packages (evolution-data-server and evolution-data-server-common) and that caused apt to also remove key desktop packages.

To fix it, I booted into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), then chose *Enable network*. After that,  *Drop to root shell prompt*.

Then reinstalled the desktop packages with *apt install ubuntu-desktop*

That's it!

When the installation completed, I rebooted and everything went back to normal.

Comment: sounds reasonable

Comment: CTRL + ALT + F1 also works from that screen and then you can install desktop from there.

Comment: My god, every problem really is googlable. Thank you, kind stranger.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, in my case I was able to boot by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> that led me to the login. Once logged you can start the GUI by providing the startx command.

Then, again in my case, it was due to a wrong runlevel, I reverted it by giving:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

More details in [Boot systems into different targets manually - RHCSA Objective Preparation](https://linuxconfig.org/boot-systems-into-different-targets-manually-rhcsa-objective-preparation)